# How can I use a javascript custom event instead of a while loop?

Tags: javascript, events

I am trying to call a function when a constantly changing element becomes a certain value.

When `player.getCurrentTime() >= 0.95 * player.getDuration()` I want to call `handleEvent()`. What would the best way to do this be?
This is what the latest iteration of my try:

```
window.onLoad=function() {
    var player = document.getElementById("movie_player");

    player.addEventListener("customEvent", handleEvent(), false);

    function handleEvent() {
    // do something here
    }

    var myEvent = new CustomEvent("customEvent", {
        detail: {
                    time: 0.95 * getDuration()
                }
    });
    document.body.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
}
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: How is your HTML laid out? Are you using any plugins? Is your `player` object firing any kind of `change` event continuously?

Comment: Hi @JustinTivo, did my suggestion work for you? Do you have any questions regarding this that you would like to ask? Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are using YouTube player. As per its [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events), there is an `YT.PlayerState.PLAYING` event that you can use to keep track of your `getCurrentTime()`. Take a look at the below code:

```
player.addEventListener(YT.PlayerState.PLAYING, onVideoPlaying, false);

function onVideoPlaying(){
  console.log('video is playing');
  if (player.getCurrentTime() >= 0.95 * player.getDuration()){
    console.log('Here I am!');
    // do Something
  }
}
```

Also, I do not think you need to `dispatchEvent` yourself because as mentioned above, `player` is already dispatching a continuously changing event which you can utilize.

Let me know if anything is unclear or if I have missed out on any detail.

Comment: This could be the right answer if you are using this api.

Answer (score 1):

You are already using Custom Events and that code seems nearly correct, just remove the parentheses or i doubt it will work:

```
player.addEventListener("customEvent", handleEvent, false);
```

Comment: Is the event set up correctly? When `player.getCurrentTime()` is greater than `0.95 * player.getDuration()`, the event will fire?

Comment: No, looking at the sample above you just dispatch the event one time, try looking at @tahir-ahmed answer, if you are really using youtube api.